# How to stop multiprocessing.Pool with Ctrl+c? (Python 3.10) [Solved]

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I've spent several hours on research and no solution seems to work anymore. My function will take an estimated 30-50 minutes per process. If I spot flaws during the first few minutes, I don't want to wait for the processes to finish completely or have to close the terminal without killing the processes cleanly.

For simplicity, each process is assigned a function with an infinite loop. With `Ctrl+c` the complete main program should now be interrupted without getting stuck. The reason for the infinite loop is that every previous solution has worked with lists that are actually looped through. The keyboard interrupt is recognized, but only afterwards, when all processes have finished. I don't know if this has anything to do with the Python version, but that's not the requirement I would like.

I would like a simple and clean solution to this problem. That would probably help many others as well.
Thank you for your help. :)

Example:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    while True:
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(2) as p:
        p.map(f, [1, 2])
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the main program "getting stuck".  Why won't the Pool.terminate() method do what you want?  It stops all the worker processes immediately, so what if you call this function when you catch a Keyboard Interrupt?  You don't need any code added to your example to do this: if an exception occurs that causes an exit from the `with Pool(2) as p` context manager block, terminate() will be called by the context manager's `__exit__` method.

Comment: @PaulCornelius It's as simple as you say. "Getting stuck" happened with various "exotic" solutions, which is why I mentioned that in passing. In fact, someone made the same simple suggestion as you on another forum just now. My apologies for not noticing this sooner, the suggestions already out there on the internet must have messed up my thinking. I will mark the link to this post as the solution. Thank you for your contribution as well. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem Solved

In another forum this problem was discussed and solved in a simple and clean way. Here is the link for everyone else:

https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/152sfp8/how_to_stop_multiprocessingpool_with_ctrlc_python/

### Solution 1

In multiprocessing module there is an **AsyncResult** object. This includes various functions such as `get()`, `wait()` and `ready()`. While get() and wait() block, you can use **`ready()`** to wait for the result and still catch KeyboardInterrupts.

Unfortunately, only `map_async()` and `apply_async()` return an AsyncResult object.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    while True:
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with Pool(2) as p:
        result = p.map_async(f, [1, 2])
        while not result.ready():
            time.sleep(1)
```

### Solution 2

This way you can also use functions that block:

> Playing around with signals it seems that from inside child processes,
> exceptions other than KeyboardInterrupt or SystemExit propagate to the
> main process. When ctrl+c is pressed, all processes (children and main
> process) run their SIGINT handler which by default just raises
> KeyboardInterrupt. To get control out of the children, the child
> interrupt handler must raise some other exception. The exception is
> not seen by the way because the main process has its hands full with
> its own KeyboardInterrupt.

Basically, the **SIGINT** handler can also return None.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from signal import signal, SIGINT

def initializer():
    signal(SIGINT, lambda: None)

def f(x):
    while True:
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(n, initializer) as p:
        p.map(f, [1, 2])
```

Comment: Can you please provide more information about the solution that you found in the reference link and post it directly here on your response?

Answer (score 0):

For your scenario using `apply_async` is better than `map` so you can implement it like this:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
import signal

def f(x):
    while True:
        pass

def init_worker():
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(2, init_worker) as p:
        processes = [p.apply_async(f, (i,)) for i in [1, 2]]
        try:
            # Check for keyboard interrupts while the processes are running
            for process in processes:
                process.get(timeout=5)  # Adjust the timeout as needed
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("Keyboard interrupt received. Stopping processes...")
            p.terminate()
            p.join()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But that's really not a good solution. First the main problem: The process will work for 30-50 minutes until it returns a result. So a timeout doesn't help. I'm also wondering why you're using apply_async, maybe you could have explained why. Why not map_async instead?

Answer (score 0):

You need the "driver" and sub-processing code to somehow collaborate. An Event can be useful for this.

Let's say that your sub-process is running in some kind of loop, then you just need that process to check an Event from time to time. If the event is set then it can terminate gracefully.

Something like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager
from signal import signal, SIGINT, SIG_IGN
from time import sleep

N = 10

def do_work(t):
    e, x = t
    while True: # infinite loop
        sleep(1) # do some work
        if e.is_set(): # check the Event
            break # process terminates
    return x

def ignore():
    signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN)

def main():
    with Manager() as manager:
        e = manager.Event() # event is not set initially
        with Pool(N, ignore) as pool:
            results = pool.map_async(do_work, [(e, i) for i in range(N)])
            print('Blocking... Interrupt (Ctrl-C or Ctrl-Break) to continue')
            while True:
                try:
                    for r in results.get(): # block
                        print(r)
                    break
                except KeyboardInterrupt:
                    e.set()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Output:**

```
Blocking... Interrupt (Ctrl-C or Ctrl-Break) to continue
^C0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Did you test your code? Do you realize you created a deadlock? After results.get() an exception is expected, which never occurs because it is set in the exept block, which in the end is never reached.

Comment: Yes I did test the code. It blocks intentionally awaiting the keyboard interrupt. Did you try running it then initiate a keyboard interrupt (Ctrl-C)? *print('Blocking... Interrupt (Ctrl-C) to continue')* offers a clue as to how you should use it

Comment: The main process is stuck in the try block after the get() function. It can't detect a keyboard interrupt, I've tried.

Comment: @Nanilla Are you running this in Jupyter or something similar? If so, try a copy'n'paste of the code in this answer, write to a py script and run it from a command line. You have to ask yourself why the KeyboardInterrupt is (apparently) not working in your environment. My test rig is Python 3.11.4, MacOS 13.4.1, 3GHz 10-Core Intel Xeon W, 32GB RAM

Comment: What? No! It's the programmer's job to check that code works in different environments. But if it helps: I ran the complete code untouched via VS Code and additionally via CMD. OS is Windows 10.

Comment: Maybe someone else will be able to figure out what you're doing wrong (apart from using Windows). There is no reason that I know of why this code would not be portable

Comment: First of all, I'm not doing anything wrong. I also have no idea why the keyboard interrupt is handled differently on different operating systems.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/ctrl-c-and-ctrl-break-signals

Comment: You can't even interrupt the kernel in Spyder. Why are you acting so arrogant?

Comment: AsyncResult.get on Windows doesn't appear to be interruptable by CTRL-C. Switching to AsyncResult.get(t) and 'continue'ing on multiprocessing.TimeoutError fixes the blocking issue. This describes the problem (the Python lock implementation on Windows) https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/82609